# SDL code working fine only on my computer

Tags: c++

So i'm learning c++ and decided to try SDL out so I can get used to working with classes. The game is basically a space shooter game , so i wrote some code that permits the "shooting of bullets".The code works fine on my computer , the bullets travel from point X to point Y without a problem.When i tried to run the game on 2 different computers the "bullets" are very buggy (they disappear and reapper at random and such) .The rest of the game works fine. I tested the framerate on both computers and the fps is over 300

Does anyone know what causes this and how to solve it?

Here's some code (for the bullets) if you need it for some reason:

```
//LOAD BULLET IF FREE

if(bulletEnemyCooldown.getTicks() > bulletEnemyCooldownVar)
{
    bulletEnemyCooldown.reset();

    for (int i = 0; i < kShips; i++)
    {
        if(!evilShip[i].getIfDead())
        {
            for(int j=0; j<99; j++)
            {
                if (evilShip[i].getIfBulletFree(j))
                {
                    evilShip[i].setKBullets(evilShip[i].getkBullets() + 1);
                    evilShip[i].setRectPos(evilShip[i].getPosX(),evilShip[i].getPosY(),j);
                    evilShip[i].setIfBulletFree(false,j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//CHANGE BULLET POS IF SLOT OCC AND RENDER

for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= kShips; i2++)
{
    if(!evilShip[i2].getIfDead())
    {
        for(int j2 = 0; j2<evilShip[i2].getkBullets(); j2++)
        {
            if (evilShip[i2].getIfBulletFree(j2) == false)
            {
                evilShip[i2].setBulletRectY( evilShip[i2].getBulletRectY(j2) + bulletS,j2);
                enemy_bullet_texture.render(gRenderer, evilShip[i2].getBulletRectX(j2), evilShip[i2].getBulletRectY(j2));
                evilShip[i2].setBulletDis(evilShip[i2].getBulletDis(j2) + bulletS,j2);
            }

        }
    }
}

//CHECK FOR ANY COLLISION AND FREE BULLET IF FOUND

for (int i = 0; i < kShips; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < evilShip[i].getkBullets(); j++)
    {
        if(!evilShip[i].getIfDead())
        {
            if (checkCollision(evilShip[i].getBulletPosRect(j), mainShip.getmCollider()))
            {
                evilShip[i].setIfBulletFree(true,j);
                evilShip[i].setBulletDis(0,j);
                evilShip[i].setKBullets( evilShip[i].getkBullets() - 1);
                evilShip[i].setRectPos(0,0,j);

                boolMainShipContact = true;

                mainShip.curSetHP(mainShip.curGetHP() - evilShip[i].curGetATK());
                kShipContact = i;

                score -= rand()%(10 * currentLevel);
            }
        }

        // FREE BULLET IF FOUND OFF SCREEN

        if (evilShip[i].getBulletDis(j) > SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        {
            evilShip[i].setIfBulletFree(true,j);
            evilShip[i].setBulletDis(0,j);
            evilShip[i].setKBullets(evilShip[i].getkBullets() - 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your game loop look like? Are you using a fixed step?

Comment: [link]http://cpp.sh/6hdak

Comment: I use  (SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC )

Comment: `decided to try SDL out so I can get used to working with classes` - that's a very interesting choice, considering SDL is a pure C library.

Comment: hmm so is there a library that is pure C++ without C ?

Comment: @SoLix There is nothing wrong, of course, with using a C library, such as SDL, in C++. However, if your aim is to get familiar with classes in C++ and you're interested in programming graphics, you might want to take a look at [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) - it is a C++ library, which in terms of functionality is similar to SDL. (I'm not saying one of them is *better* than the other, just pointing out the difference in language they are written in.)

Comment: @TerraPass i got you